# Why does pytest show some of my test file path in a weird way?

Tags: pytest

I go into my project and run:

```
py.test -vvv .
```

And some of the results look ok:

```
my/test/path.py::some_test_name PASSED
```

And some look weird, like this:

```
my/test/path.py <- ../../../../../../../../../root/some_folder/my/test/path.py::some_other_test_name PASSED
```

This varies per test file, even if they are in the same folder. I don't see any notable difference between the code in those test files.

Comment: Can you list the versions of pytest and python you're running, and what platform you're on?